TYPO3 13 Set ignores setup.typoscript?
I am trying to understand how to set up a basic sitepackage in TYPO3 13 using the new sets and I must be missing a simple step that the tutorial does not mention.
I have a simple set that is just a name and label that has been added to the page using the Sites module.
The only other thing I have is setup.typoscript in the same folder as the set config.yaml.
The setup just contains a basic Hello World.
But viewing the page gives me #1607585445 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\InternalServerErrorException No page configured for type=0. So it's ignoring the typoscript file.
How do I make it use the setup.typoscript in the set folder?
Version tested: TYPO3 13.4 (Composer and non-composer)
Test environment made using Laragon on windows.
Configuration/Sets/Foo/config.yaml:
name: foo/bar
label: "Bar"

Configuration/Sets/Foo/setup.typoscript:
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = Hello World!
}

typo3conf/sites/foo/config.yaml:
base: 'http://typo3-13.test/foo'
dependencies:
  - foo/bar
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    navigationTitle: English
    flag: us
rootPageId: 1
websiteTitle: ''


Other things I have tried:

Temporarily added a template to the root page via the List module.
Confirmed the typoscript works and I am looking at the correct
frontend page.
Added a page.tsconfig file to the Set and this works    as
expected.


Please add the documentation link you use. I'm part of documentation team, maybe we can update a specific part. Please remove TS template (sys_template) from your page as it may override TS from site settings. Is your page marked as root page in page properties? Have you tried Flush Cache in Installtool? And at least: It's always good to add content of setup.typoscript and config.yaml here.

Normally, there's nothing special to do. In the SiteConfiguration you haveunder dependencies the name of your set (e.g. "me/my-website") and exactly this name is in your sets config.yaml as name: me/my-website. Be aware, that you have a subfolder below even if you have only one set (Configuration/Sets/MySite/config.yaml)

@StefanFrömken Just the basic tutorial, now linked above. Page has no template. Marked as root. Cache flushed. Files added above.

@JulianHofmann Added the files above for reference. It all pretty basic, so I guess I am doing something stupid.

I tested your Site Sets in an empty, fresh TYPO3 v13.4 installation and it works perfectly fine  Are you sure that you accessed your site through the URI http://typo3-13.test/foo? Maybe try to adjust the base property.

@Michael I just fresh installed 13.4 (non-composer) and the page gives 500 error. If I add a template via the list module and put the hello world in there, it works, so definately the right uri.

Please check your "Site Management > TypoScript > Active TypoScript". Does it show your desired TypoScript in "Setup"?

Is your SiteSet shown in the new select box of the site module? Another idea would be to place the dependencies at the end of your SiteConfiguration (even if nothing should actually be overwritten/change in the example).

@JulianHofmann "Active Typoscript" does not show the hello world script. The SiteSet is shown in the site module and is on the "selected Items" side. The site config was autogenerated like that, I tried moving dependencies to the bottom but it made no difference.

You have already tried to add a template on the root page. Have you put some TypoScript there, or have you imported the TS from your Set? If not so far, try the latter. (I'm slowly running out of ideas... :-/ )

@JulianHofmann Typoscript added in the template the old way works fine. I see no way to import typoscript from the set, but it seems like it would be redundant to have a template and a set, no? My only theory at the moment is that Laragon or PHP might have some setting missing that would cause this not to work, but I have no idea what that would be...

Had the same problem and resolved it by deleting the typoscript record assigned to the root page.

I have no record on the root page. It is a fresh bare bones install with nothing but a blank root page and the site configuration mentioned above.

I had the same problem and this solved my problem!
